# Replace single backslash with double backslash

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, backslash

It seems simple enough, right? Well, I don't know.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, "\\", "\\\\\\");
```

However, I'm receiving an error,

> ArgumentException was unhandled - parsing "\" - Illegal \ at end of pattern.

How do I do this?

Comment: Unless you're doing something more complicated in the same pattern, have you considered `input = input.Replace(@"\", @"\\");`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first one should be `"\\\\"`, not `"\\"`. It works like this:

- You have written `"\\"`.
- This translates to the sequence `\` in a string.
- The regex engine then reads this, which translates as backslash which isn't escaping anything, so it throws an error.

With regex, it's much easier to use a "verbatim string". In this case the verbatim string would be `@"\\"`. When using verbatim strings you only have to consider escaping for the regex engine, as backslashes are treated literally. The second string will also be `@"\\"`, as it will not be interpreted by the regex engine.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to replace one backslash with two, it might be clearer to eliminate one level of escaping in the regular expression by using `@"..."` as the format for your string literals, also known as a verbatim string. It is then easier to see that

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\\", @"\\");
```

is a replacement from `\` to `\\`.

Comment: This will replace 1 backslash with 4 backslashes

Answer (score 6):

I know it's too late to help you, maybe someone else will benefit from this. Anyway this worked for me:

```
text = text.Replace(@"\",@"\\");
```

and I find it even more simplier.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

```
 var result = Regex.Replace(@"afd\tas\asfd\", @"\\", @"\\");
```

The first parameter is string \\ which is \ in regex.
The second parameter is not processed by regex, so it will put it as is, when replacing.

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to use the input in a regex pattern later, it can be a good idea to use Regex.Encode.

```
input = Regex.Escape(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all these examples, but without success.
I had a "//" and I didn't want to change it. I only needed to change the "/"

This regex helped me:

- string myString = "https://example.com/example/example/example";
- string result = Regex.Replace(myString, @"(?<!/)/(?!/)", "//");
- and I got - "https://example.com//example//example//example"