# Regex Everything except !"#$'*+,/:;\`|

Tags: regex

I want every character possible (letters,numbers,everyting) except: `!"#$'*+,/:;\`|`

```
Is this correct? [^!"#$'*+,/:;\`|]
```

I made it work using http://www.regextester.com/ and your suggestions

```
*WORKS--> [^!"#$'*+,/:;\\`|]
```

Comment: regex101.com ... you can try here....and come back with a specific question....and also tag the flavor of regex being used by you

Comment: My code ignore the "\" ...any tips?

Comment: Which language you use it for?

Comment: To match a literal ``\``, you need to double it. Please state your programming language and post the code you have.

Comment: Why do not accept `\\` ? What language are you using?

Comment: the doble \\ fixed my problem

Comment: Read this: _http://stackoverflow.com/q/6105476/4227915_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex pattern to match a single `\`:

```
\\
```

It means you need to escape a backslash by adding another backslash to it. So, you need to use

```
[^!"#$'*+,/:;\\`|]
             ^^
```

Note that if you use it in a regular string  literal in some programming language, you will have to double each of the backslashes (so that there are 4 backslashes).